# How to append a where clause to an Entity Framework ObjectSet

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I would like to append a set of conditional where clauses onto the end of an ObjectSet. However, the clauses do not get executed and instead the original query is run, for example:

```
using (Entities context = new Entities()){
var q = context.AuditLogs;
q.Where(o => o.WebsiteId == 1);
}
```

The where clause is not executed and the full result set is returned
I could instead use IQueryAble as in:

```
var q = context.AuditLogs.AsQueryable();
q = q.Where(o => o.WebsiteId == 1);
```

However this loses me the power of being able to use .Include to eager load my related entities.

Comment: In your first example, you aren't setting q to the result of q.Where(o => o.WebsiteId == 1);

Comment: yes, you cant do that (well at least it doesn let me do that) as it cant implicitly convert from ObjectSet to Iqueryable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't. at any point before executing the query, you would still be able to cast it back to *ObjectQuery<T>* and invoke methods like *Include* on it:

```
var query = context.AuditLogs.AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(o => o.WebsiteId == 1);
var auditLog = ((ObjectQuery<AuditLog>)query).Include("yourNavPropertyName")
                                             .ToList();
```

If your intention is to build up a criteria incrementally, then the other option would be to leverage *EntitySQL* with *QueryBuilder* methods:

```
var query = context.AuditLogs.Where("it.WebsiteId = 1");
query = query.Where("...");
var auditLog = query.Include("yourNavPropertyName")
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: to avoid the cast at the end, can you do something like context.AuditLogs.Include("navProp").AsQueryable(); ? Or will that still execute the entire result set then filter it down client-side?

Answer (score 1):

Just some good old fashioned linq would suffice here.  Assuming you had a property named SiteOwner you could accomplish what your trying to do with the below query

```
using (Entities context = new Entities()){
  var webSites = from sites in context.AuditLogs.Include("SiteOwner")
                 where sites.WebSiteId == 1
                 select sites;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that wasn't what i was looking for, include only works when using ObjectSet whereas a I needed a combination of functionality between IQueryable and Object set as in Morteza's answer