# Entity Framework 6: Dynamically build search clause against DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i use EF v5/6. i want to know how could i build where clause dynamically when user will try to add search filter dynamically through UI.

see the UI first
[image]

now end user will add as many as filter through the above UI and try to search database.

i try to search google for some solution as a result i can add multiple search to my db table with EF and i found few. here is few links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5595591/6188148

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24824290/6188148

the above guide line is tough for me to understand. so i am looking something easy.

**this link bit close to my requirement** https://stackoverflow.com/a/16646241/6188148  but still i am not getting idea how to customize their code to use for my scenario.

so my request anyone can help with a small sample code which help me to get the things done.

Comment: With performance in mind for advanced searches like this, I would recommend using a dedicated product such as  [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/), I spent days trying to do something similar inside of EF only discover how poorly it performed on bigger data.

Comment: Elasticsearch can fetch data from sql server using EF.....i have no idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are able to build a sub-condition from each line in your GUI. For example, the first line would be similar to

```
string userInputName = "john";
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> condition1 = person => person.Name.Contains(userInputName);
```

And can be used as

```
var selection = db.Persons.Where(condition1).ToList();
```

For multiple sub-conditions, `and` is just a concatenation of `Where` conditions:

```
var conditions = new List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>() { condition1, condition2, ... };

IQueryable<Person> query = db.Persons;
foreach (var condition in conditions)
{
    query = query.Where(condition);
}
var selection = query.ToList();
```

The little trickier part comes with the `or` conditions. Suppose you have normalized your conditions into groups of alternative `and` conditions ([disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)), then you get multiple groups of valid results. For the sake of simplicity, I keep it at 2 groups here, but it can be generalized the same way as the `and` conditions:

The `or` can be represented by the `Union` operation on sub-queries.

```
var conditions1 = new List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>() { condition1, condition2, ... };
IQueryable<Person> query1 = // see above construction logic for 'and' conditions
var conditions2 = new List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>() { condition5, condition6, ... };
IQueryable<Person> query2 = // see above construction logic for 'and' conditions

IQueryable<Person> query = query1.Union(query2);
var selection = query.ToList();
```

A few last words: consider using some established filter/search frameworks instead. This approach is probably neither the prettiest nor the fastest you can find.

---

As requested, a small example with some in-memory data. Note this is not 100% equivalent to Linq-to-entities. For example, string comparison will deal with upper-lower case differently and maybe not every kind of condition is allowed for SQL.

```
public enum TypeOfContact
{
    Unknown,
    Email
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }

    public TypeOfContact ContactType { get; set; }

    public string ContactValue { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // test data to simulate a database table
        var Persons = new List<Person>
        {
            // + All conditions met
            new Person { Name = "john doe", Birth = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1), ContactType = TypeOfContact.Email, ContactValue = "john.doe@email.com" },
            // - Not in result
            new Person { Name = "danny doe", Birth = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), ContactType = TypeOfContact.Email, ContactValue = "johndoe@hotmail.com" },
            // + Name contains john
            new Person { Name = "john doe", Birth = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), ContactType = TypeOfContact.Unknown, ContactValue = "" },
            // + Birth, ContactType and ContactValue correct
            new Person { Name = "justin", Birth = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), ContactType = TypeOfContact.Email, ContactValue = "slenderman@email.com" },
            // - Not in result because Name and Birth are wrong
            new Person { Name = "jonny", Birth = new DateTime(1979, 1, 1), ContactType = TypeOfContact.Email, ContactValue = "you-know-who@email.com" },
            // - Not in result
            new Person { Name = "jenny doe", Birth = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1), ContactType = TypeOfContact.Unknown, ContactValue = "" },
        }.AsQueryable();

        // single-line-conditions
        Expression<Func<Person, bool>> c1 = p => p.Name.Contains("john");
        Expression<Func<Person, bool>> c2 = p => p.Birth.Date >= new DateTime(1980, 1, 1);
        Expression<Func<Person, bool>> c3 = p => p.ContactType == TypeOfContact.Email;
        Expression<Func<Person, bool>> c4 = p => p.ContactValue.EndsWith("@email.com");

        // DNF groups: outer list = or; inner list = and
        // c1 or (c2 and c3 and c4)
        var conditionList = new List<List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>>
        {
            new List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>
            {
                c1,
            },
            new List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>
            {
                c2,
                c3,
                c4,
            },
        };

        var andSubResults = new List<IQueryable<Person>>();
        foreach (var andQueries in conditionList)
        {
            var subQuery = Persons;
            foreach (var andQuery in andQueries)
            {
                subQuery = subQuery.Where(andQuery);
            }
            andSubResults.Add(subQuery);
        }
        var query = andSubResults.FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (var subResult in andSubResults.Skip(1))
        {
            query = query.Union(subResult);
        }
        var selection = query.ToList();
        // just check the result in debugger
    }
}
```

Comment: i would like to just a small request can you give me small but full working example on this issue if possible. thanks

Comment: i would like to go for condition iteration loop highlighted in your example. 

say this one.......`var conditions = new List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>() { condition1, condition2, ... };

IQueryable<Person> query = db.Persons;
foreach (var condition in conditions)
{
    query = query.Where(condition);
}
var selection = query.ToList();`

Comment: @MonojitSarkar a *small but full working example* would include to set up an actual database, because otherwise it's just an in-memory example which works a bit different from linq-to-entities. I feel like this would exceed the scope of an answer. I'll still write a small in-memory example.

Answer (score 0):

@grek40's answer gave me the clues I needed for this approach. I only have a few anded conditions, not sure if it works with ored conditions.

```
using (var theDb = new project_dbEntities())
{
    IQueryable<TheEntityClass> query = theDbContext.TheEntityClass;

    if (!showInactive)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.active);
    }

    if (selectedYearId != years.ALL_YEARS)
    {
        var yearToFilter = years.GetById(selectedYearId);
        query = query.Where(x => x.first_effective_date >= yearToFilter.start &&
                                 x.first_effective_date <= yearToFilter.end);
    }

    var entities = query
        .Include(nameof(TheChildEntity))
        .OrderBy(x => x.name)
        .ToList();

    return View(new IndexViewModel(entities));
}
```