# EF6 generates WHERE clause in unexpected order

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I'm using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24824290) to form an `Expression<Func<Proposal, bool>>` object (where `Proposal` is an entity type in my app), according to the searching criteria input on a WebForm page by users. The string representation of the resulting object I see during debugging is like this:

```cs
{Param_0 => (
  (
    (
      (Param_0.SubmitDate >= value(Proposals+<>c__DisplayClass4_0).submitDateBegin)
      AndAlso (Param_0.SubmitDate <= value(Proposals+<>c__DisplayClass4_0).submitDateEnd)
    ) AndAlso (Param_0.ProposingOrgNode.ID == value(Proposals+<>c__DisplayClass4_0).proposingOrgNode.ID)
  ) AndAlso value(Proposals+<>c__DisplayClass4_0).undertakerRelations.Contains(Param_0.UndertakerRelation)
)}
```

(I assume `Proposals+<>c__DisplayClass4_0` means some compiler magic played on my "Proposals.aspx" page object.)

I pass this object into `myDbContextObj.Proposals.Where()`, expecting the order of the expressions in the SQL WHERE clause which EF6 generates would match that of the above. However the generated WHERE clause is like this:

```sql
WHERE ([Extent1].[UndertakerRelation] IN (N'A', N'B', N'C'))
  AND ([Extent1].[SubmitDate] >= @p__linq__0)
  AND ([Extent1].[SubmitDate] <= @p__linq__1)
  AND (([Extent1].[ProposingOrgNodeID] = @p__linq__2) OR (([Extent1].[ProposingOrgNodeID] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL)))
```

The "UndertakerRelation" condition jumps ahead as the first one of the whole clause.

Why is this happening? How can I stop this behavior, ensuring that EF6 generates the expressions in supposed order?

.NET Framework version: 4.8
EF version: 6.4.4 (Not EF Core)
SQL Sever version: 2019 LocalDB

(The reason I care about this issue: I've heard that the order of the expressions in WHERE clause affects if indexes are used or not, and hence the selectivity and performance.)

Comment: _"I've heard that the order of the expressions in WHERE clause affects if indexes are used or not, and hence the selectivity and performance."_ - And did you check if it does in your case? Because **if** _it does not_ you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: AFAIK, [the order of the conditions in the `where` clause is meaningless.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3152182/3094533) The optimizer will decide the best flow in which to filter the data. After all, SQL is a declarative programming language, not an imperative one.